# match until space digit combination

Tags: php, regex, regex-greedy

My goal is to match from any **space+digit+)+space** including to the next one excluding. For example:

```
1) this is an example 2) yet another example 1) with embedded pattern 2) another embedded pattern 3) still another 4) final
```

result:

```
1) this is an example 
2) yet another example 1) with embedded pattern 2) another embedded pattern 
3) still another 
4) final
```

the answer provided by [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) is alright,

```
(?:(?!\s\d+\)).)+
```

**but what if I have an embedded similar pattern inside the pattern, how to avoid this?**

### update

the only comparison or condition would be that the main enumerations will increase, never decrease: 1) 2) 3) 4) 5) so on.
 however, the embedded ones will always start from 1) again, so basically if the embedded ones are smaller than or equal to the main ones, then we skip it.

Comment: Why do you include `[^<]*`? Did you forget to told us about some html parsing you do?

Comment: because I have < at the end of each line, sometimes! so I was trying to catch the end of my lines using < however some of the lines don't end similarly. so, the only way is to catch until the next space digit ) space

Comment: Then [edit] your question with correct information ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is used in php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(\d+\) [A-Za-z+ ]+)
```

See demo: https://regex101.com/r/T8nadr/1